# Exception thrown when ExecuteScalar returns NULL

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a stored procedure which returns flag values based on certain conditions. The stored procedure does not return a `NULL` value, it returns 1, 2, or 3 based on some condition. But when I debug, my ADO.NET code throws an exception because `ExecuteScalar` is returning `NULL`.

Here is my ADO.NET code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_checkifexists", con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regno",regno);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
cmd.Parameters["@flag"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
con.Open();

// Error occcurs here

int NoOfRows = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
con.Close();
int flag = (int)cmd.Parameters["@flag"].Value;
return flag;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you update the question with your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar`  is for Stored procs that return a resultset with one row, and one column, *not* to get the value that the stored proc returns via a `return` statement.  So you have to have a `Select` statement in the stored proc.  Do you?

Answer (score 0):

if the result is like `1,2,3` then `Convert.ToInt16` will fail. you need to have values like `1`

```
//check what you have return from  `ExecuteScalar` 

var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if(obj  != DBNull.Value)
{
  //if you have received obj as `1` or `2` etc
  int NoOfRows = Convert.ToInt16(obj) ;
  if you have received obj as `1,2,3`
  List<Int16> valueList = obj.ToString().Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt16(x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
```

it is an integer value so, it has to be

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
```

thanks anyways!